# Hibernate Envers inserting into REVINFO even after modifying its name in custom revision entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am creating a project with hibernate auditing enabled with envers. I have changed the name of REVINFO table by creating CustomRevisionEntity class as follows:

**CustomRevisionEntity.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity;

import myproject.util.CustomRevisionListener;


@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
@Table( name = "MYDB.TBL_REVINFO")
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**CustomRevisionListener.java**

```
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;

public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

@Override
public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
}
}
```

Now whenever i try to add a query into the DB by running test project in my IDE, Envers inserts correctly into TBL_REVINFO.

But whenever I make a standalone jar of my project, Envers inserts into REVINFO table and thus causing error.

**DB Connection Properties for jar**

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB
db.username=username
db.password=******
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, i never wrote custom audition-tables by myself, i always used the generated audition-table-classes.

Comment: how do you "make a standalone jar"? When it works, how do you run your application? Are you bundling everything in the jar, also the dependencies?

Comment: Yes every dependency is bundled in the jar.

Comment: This might be a silly questio, but you didn't create the `CustomRevisionListener` and `CustomRevisionEntity` in the test source packages did you?